# jQuery - If ANY Select within a div has a value

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement

Been having lot's of trouble with this one.  Let's say I had the following html:

```
<div id='step_1'>

  <select name='select_1' id='choose'>
    <option value='select one'>Select One</option>
    <option value='yes'>Yes</option>
    <option value='no'>No</option>
  </select>

  <select name='select_2' id='choose_again'>
    <option value='select one'>Select One</option>
    <option value='yes'>Yes</option>
    <option value='no'>No</option>
  </select>

  <button id='submit'>button</button>

</div>
```

I have many of these, so what I'm trying to do is return false if ANY 'select' has the value of 'Select One' then alert them. The jQuery i have so far looks as so:

```
$('#submit').click(function() {
if ($('#step_1 select[value="select one"]').length() == 0) {
    //succeed
} else {
    alert('Please select yes or no!');
    return false;
}

});
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance, I love this website! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('#submit').click(function(e) {
   var flag = true;
    $('select').each(function(){
     if($(this).val() == "select one"){
        alert("please select a value in " + $(this).attr("name"));
         flag = false;
     }
   });
    if(flag){
     alert('perfect');    
    }else{
      e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

EXAMPLE : http://jsfiddle.net/raj_er04/3kHVY/1/

Quick note: If you want the alert to only show once rather than once per each 'select one', simply move the alert() into the else{ statement. thanks again for this answer!

Comment: if the first one says 'yes' or 'no' and the second one still says 'select one', it returns correct. It should return 'please select one' if ANY of them have that value. Thanks for the help though I highly appreciate it!

Comment: thanks so much! i would've never figured this one out on my own

Comment: one more thing, do you know how i can make that alert only show one time, even though both are not selected?

Comment: you can move that to else condtion thats all.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with $.each():

```
$('#step_1').find('SELECT').each( function() {
    if( $(this).val() === 'select one' ) {
        alert('Please select yes or no!');
        return false;
    }
});
```

Note that returning false will prevent the loop from continuing once a missing field is found.

Comment: so close!! This one works but if the FIRST one is selected, even though the second one isn't, it still submits although the alert does pop up first.. in other words it still runs the else statement that I'm using, but for some reason runs what is in the 'if' first.. any ideas? thanks so much for the help though!

Comment: Right, it's up to you to add a flag and handle the action accordingly.  Instead of an alert, you could add a variable to test for the status after the iteration and move the alert outside of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Your test fails because `length` is not a method. It is a property. Remove the `()`. If you look in your debugger you should see a warning about this.

Also, your selector should be checking the selected option, not the select list itself.

http://jsfiddle.net/7PPs4/

```
$('#submit').click(function() {
    $foo = $('#step_1 select option:selected[value="select one"]');
    alert($foo.length);
});
```