# JQuery identify each Div with select value of No

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have a form with 50 or so select responses in them.  Responses can be Yes, No, N/A.  These 50 responses are group among 20 divs.  Some divs have one response, others have multiple.

What I would like to do and for each div, I would like to identify the div that has at least one response selected as no.  I will use that div value to show/hide another div that will be used to collect user responses down the line in our line of questioning.

Here is a related question: [jQuery - If ANY Select within a div has a value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8937227/jquery-if-any-select-within-a-div-has-a-value)

From that, here is the code to just identify if the div has a question with a "No" response.  The code is correctly working to loop through each of the divs that contain the response elements (as shown in the page alerts).  However, the code to detect the "No" response to the select values is not working:

```
    jq('[id$=LARBlock]').each( function() {
       var flag = true;
        jq('select').each(function(){
        if( jq(this).val() === 'No' ) {
            //alert("No selected a value in " + jq(this).attr("name"));
             flag = false;
             return false;
         }
       });
        if(flag){
         alert('should show for this block ' + jq(this).attr("id"));    
        }else{
            alert('should not show for this block ' + jq(this).attr("id"));   
          //e.preventDefault();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

target all selects with a value of `No`, and *then* find the closest element with an ID ending with LARBlock :

```
$('select[value="No"]').closest('[id$="LARBlock"]'). stuff()
```